# Pass multiple columns from dataframe into function with multiprocessing or concurrent.futures

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, python-3.6, concurrent.futures

**Question:** How can I pass the dataframe's columns into a function for each row using `multiprocessing` or `concurrent.futures`?

**Details:**
For each row in `df`, I want to pass its columns `leader` and `years` into the function `print_sentences()`. I want to use the function in a parallel way where each row is printed asynchronously. For example, I want to make use of `concurrent.futures.Executor.map`.

It needs to be in `Python 3.6.`

**Reprex:** My actual problem is computationally demanding, so here is a simplified `reprex`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import concurrent.futures

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["Larry", 3, "Germany"], ["Jerry", 5, "Sweden"], ["George", 12, "UK"]]),
                   columns=['leader', 'years', 'score'])

def print_sentences(df):

    print(df["leader"] + " has been leader for " + df["years"] + " years")


print_sentences(df)
```

**Background:**
Other questions related to this issue seem to deal with object types other than a `dataframe`.

My specific issue begins when I read in a `.csv`, the dataframe. I want pass this dataframe's columns, for each of its rows, into some function. My actual function (dramatically simplified for a reprex) is computationally demanding. It scrapes data and saves it to a `.json`. Each row therefore acts a different query (inputting a different leader's name and score, for example).

To optimise this, I want the rows to map into the function in a parallel way.

I have simplified my problem with the `reprex` above.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

#Edits made to reflect your use case.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import cpu_count, Pool

cores = cpu_count() #Number of CPU cores on your system
partitions = cores #Define as many partitions as you want

def parallelize(data, func):
    data_split = np.array_split(data, partitions)
    pool = Pool(cores)
    data = pd.concat(pool.map(func, data_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return data

def print_sentences(cols):
    leader, years = cols[0], cols[1]
    print(leader + " has been leader for " + years + " years")


df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["Larry", 3, "Germany"], ["Jerry", 5, "Sweden"], 
                           ["George", 12, "UK"]]),
                           columns=['leader', 'years', 'score'])

data = df.copy()

data = parallelize(data, print_sentences)

data.apply(print_sentences, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! Are you able to edit this answer to include my reprex (e.g. where data = df)? I can't seem to make your code run.

Comment: What seems to be the issue?

Comment: Your answer doesn't include my data (df) or my function (print_sentences).